Australia Visa Rejection
I recently applied for Australia Tourist Visa but I was rejected with the following reason; But I had given bank statement ( with almost 4500 USD ), employment verification letter,Leave letter NOC ( from Employer ) and payslips

The applicant has provided limited details of their own financial circumstances and has not
provided evidence of savings or other streams of revenue. In assessing this application
I have considered that the applicant has provided limited evidence of their financial
circumstances, and noting the current economic circumstances in India, I am not satisfied the
applicant’s personal financial circumstances would be an incentive for them to return to their
home country. The applicant has also not demonstrated that they have sufficiently strong
commitments in India that would be an incentive for them to return to India at the end of their
proposed stay in Australia.

Edit from a comment by OP: I have travelled to only Indonesia before this and my parents are staying back in India (for ties to home).

What is your actual question? Applying for a visa is not like taking an exam, you might answer all questions correct but still fail, 4500 dollar is a nice amount but not much compared to the cost of living in Australia, a month for a typical tourist will cost that much.

What prior travel history do you have? Other ties to India apart from your job?

$4500 is not a lot, and considering the flights and accommodations may not be enough at all to reasonably sustain yourself if you're planing a long enough vacation. I think a month is a bit of a stretch, I wouldn't expect this to be enough for no more than a couple of weeks. I can see why the VO would be cautious.

More importantly than how much savings you had (not that the balance at a given point does not necessarily represent savings), your monthly income is probably more important, and should be compared to wages and cost of living in Australia. It is weird however that they state you have provided “limited details” and “no evidence” if you provided the documents to you cite, unless your demonstrated income is indeed very low (by Australian standards).

@Traveller I have travelled to only Indonesia before this and my parents are staying back in India ( for ties to home )

@SrivathsavM Neither of those are strong enough IMHO.

IMO, your parents remaining in their home country is NOT proof of "incentive to return to " .. the officer reviewing your app has no idea at all of your personal relationship to your parents, and there are as many wanting to distance themselves as not. A spouse and/or children remaining would be, a decent job, with a good salary (as compared to the country of visit, not necessarily your home country), etc. Also, many confuse savings with salary. They want to see a good earning history, not a life savings.

Also, compare your income to your savings. (I don't know any of your particulars other than what you posted, so I'm using this as an example only) You say you have an equivalent of $4500 in a savings account. If you are 20 (I don't know your age) and if you earn the equivalent of $250 a year (I don't know your earnings), then that will raise flags. (i.e. you can't have saved that much with that earning rate, so where did it actually come from?) Please note, I'm not meaning to be critical to you as much as for other readers of the question.

The Australian tourist visa refusal rate for Indian citizens is around 30%. Little point applying IMHO unless you have an impeccable and extensive travel history, and compelling ties to home.
